# Change format of Excel

Tags: excel, format

So I'd like to essentially transpose the format of an Excel file. The original format is below:

```
                   **2015-03-08          2015-03-08          2015-03-15          2015-03-15**
**brand_code         All New bookings    Average Lead Time   All New bookings         Average lead time**
Brand A              2                   7.84                4                        4.54
Brand B              6                   9.63                9                        2.34
```

I'd like to convert this format to the one shown below:

```
Category                     2015-03-08          2015-03-15
All new bookings(Brand A)    2                   4
All new bookings(Brand B)    6                   9
Average Lead Time(Brand A)   7.84                4.54
Average Lead Time(Brand B)   9.63                2.34
```

I'd like to do this in Excel itself preferably. I do not want to write any R or other code for this. Some easy-to-use freeware would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

First unpivot (there is a step-by-step guide and other references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120)) then add a column on the left and move/copy or fill it with `All New bookings` / `Average Lead Time` repeating to suit and label that `Category`. Concatenate the first to two columns into a third if desired. Now create a new PivotTable with layout to suit.